# MVVMCross: Is it possible to use Storyboard with ICommand navigation?

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard, mvvmcross

I've spent the last few days trying to figure out a way to get around the warning:

> mvx: Warning:   8.93 Exception masked MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type FCX.iOS.TimesheetView
>         at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic) [0x00094] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:326 
>     at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:222 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.MvxTouchViewsContainer.CreateView (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.MvxCanCreateTouchViewExtensionMethods.CreateViewControllerFor (IMvxCanCreateTouchView view, Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Cirrious
>   .MvvmCross.Touch.Views.Presenters.MvxTouchViewPresenter.Show (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.MvxTouchViewDispatcher+<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3 () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxMainThreadDispatcher.ExceptionMaskedAction (System.Action action) [0x00000] in :0

It appears the navigation is looking for this constructor:

```
    public TimesheetView ()
    {
    }
```

When I WANT it to use this constructor (for storyboard purposes):

```
    public TimesheetView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }
```

I've been trying to bind a button from one view to the following ICommand:

```
    private MvxCommand _NewTimesheetCommand;
    public ICommand NewTimesheetCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _NewTimesheetCommand =  _NewTimesheetCommand ?? new MvxCommand(() => {
                ShowViewModel<TimesheetViewModel>(new TimesheetViewModel.Parameters { Mode = TimesheetViewModel.ModeEnum.ADD });
            });
            return _NewTimesheetCommand;
        }
    }
```

After looking at many StackOverFlow questions, I came across this question, but it almost sounds that using storyboards REQUIRES me to use segues (in other words there isn't a way to use ICommand to change my view).

[Does MvvmCross support storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951712/does-mvvmcross-support-storyboards)

My main question:  Is it possible to use storyboards and change the view with the viewmodel?  (rather than using segues from the view)

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm I just implemented what Stuart said. Works great. (Do remember that segue's are useless this way you navigate using ShowViewModel inside the viewmodels)

```
using System;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.Presenters;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;     
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;

 namespace DigitalCatalog.UI.Touch
 {
   public class StoryBoardTouchViewPresenter : MvxTouchViewPresenter
  {
    public static UIStoryboard Storyboard = null;


    public StoryBoardTouchViewPresenter (UIApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, UIWindow window, string storyboardName, NSBundle StoryboardBundleOrNull = null) : base(applicationDelegate, window)
    {
        Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName (storyboardName, StoryboardBundleOrNull);
    }

    public override void Show (IMvxTouchView view)
    {
        MvxViewController sbView = null;

        try{
            sbView = (MvxViewController) Storyboard.InstantiateViewController (view.Request.ViewModelType.Name.Replace("Model", ""));
        }catch(Exception e){
            Console.WriteLine ("Failed to find storyboard view, did you forget to set the Storyboard ID to the ViewModel class name without the Model suffix ?" + e);
        }

        sbView.Request = view.Request;

        base.Show (sbView);
    }

}
 }
```

All you have to do now is set the AppDelegate like this :

```
public override void FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application)
    {


        StoryBoardTouchViewPresenter sbPresenter = new StoryBoardTouchViewPresenter(this, Window,"MainStoryboard_iPad");


        var setup = new Setup(this,sbPresenter);
        setup.Initialize();

        var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
        startup.Start();


        sbPresenter.MasterNavigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;

        sbPresenter.MasterNavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden(false, false);

    }
```

**LAST REMEMBER TO SET FOR EVERY VIEW IN THE STORYBOARD A STORYBOARD ID WITH THE "CLASS NAME" OF THE VIEW !!!! sadly there isn't any other way to get a view using the UIStoryboard class you can only get it by using Storyboard Ids**

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to load a `UiViewController. From a storyboard - eg see [load view form StoryBoard that does not have a Segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666168/load-view-form-storyboard-that-does-not-have-a-segue)

If you want to use this custom loading in mvvmcross, then you could override the `IMvxTouchViewCreator` so that it uses this sort of storyboard load, or you could override the `presenter` so that it loads the storyboard view directly .

Overall, though, it feels like you are fighting against storyboards if you are working this way - almost all storyboard navigation seems to be segue based. With this in mind another thing you could do is to implement a custom presenter and to get that presenter to convert ShowViewModel requests into `performSegueWithIdentifier` calls.

Comment: When you say convert the ShowViewModel request in the presenter, do you mean the Show(MvxViewModelRequest request) method?  Maybe I'm missing something very obvious, but I can't figure out how I would do this.