# MVVMCross Xamarin and storyboard

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying out MvvmCross with Xamarin 'classic'.
I've got it working with Android.

But I can't get it work for iOS. I've taken a look at the sample mentioned here (eh): [MVVMCross support for Xamarin.iOS Storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126929/mvvmcross-support-for-xamarin-ios-storyboards)

I'm really missing something.
What do i have:

- A storyboard with only 3 controls on it. a label and 2 buttons. All 3
  have names so i get the properties in the `RootViewController` class.
- The basis setup.cs
- AppDelegate.cs

  ```
  [Register("AppDelegate")]
      public partial class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate
      {

  UIWindow _window;

  public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
  {
      _window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

      StoryBoardTouchViewPresenter sbPresenter = new StoryBoardTouchViewPresenter(this, _window, "MainStoryboard");

      var setup = new Setup(this, _window);
      setup.Initialize();

      var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
      startup.Start();

      sbPresenter.MasterNavigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;

      sbPresenter.MasterNavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden(false, false);

      return true;
  }

  }
  ```

StoryBoardTouchViewPresenter (from [MVVMCross: Is it possible to use Storyboard with ICommand navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245076/mvvmcross-is-it-possible-to-use-storyboard-with-icommand-navigation)) But the API is changed.

```
public class StoryBoardTouchViewPresenter : MvxTouchViewPresenter
{
    public static UIStoryboard Storyboard = null;


    public StoryBoardTouchViewPresenter(UIApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, UIWindow window, string storyboardName, NSBundle StoryboardBundleOrNull = null)
        : base(applicationDelegate, window)
    {
        Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName(storyboardName, StoryboardBundleOrNull);
    }

    public override void Show(IMvxTouchView view)
    {
        MvxViewController sbView = null;

        try
        {
            sbView = (MvxViewController)Storyboard.InstantiateViewController(view.Request.ViewModelType.Name.Replace("Model", ""));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to find storyboard view, did you forget to set the Storyboard ID to the ViewModel class name without the Model suffix ?" + e);
        }

        sbView.Request = view.Request;

        base.Show(sbView);
    }

}
```

The default App.cs in the Core project

```
public class App : Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxApplication
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            CreatableTypes()
                .EndingWith("Service")
                .AsInterfaces()
                .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

            RegisterAppStart<ViewModels.MainViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        ITodoTaskService taskService;
        IDataManager<TodoTask> tasks;

        public MainViewModel(ITodoTaskService taskService)
        {
            this.taskService = taskService;
        }

        public async override void Start()
        {
            this.tasks = new DataManager<TodoTask>(await this.taskService.GetTodoTasksAsync());
            this.tasks.MoveFirst();

            Rebind();
            base.Start();
        }

        private void Rebind()
        {
            this.Description = this.tasks.Current.Description;

            NextCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            PreviousCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }

        private string description;

        public string Description
        {
            get { return this.description; }
            set
            {
                this.description = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Description);
            }
        }   

        private MvxCommand nextCommand;
        public MvxCommand NextCommand
        {
            get
            {
                this.nextCommand = this.nextCommand ?? new MvxCommand(NavigateToNext, CanNavigateNext);
                return this.nextCommand;
            }
        }

        private bool CanNavigateNext()
        {
            return this.tasks.CanMoveNext;
        }

        public void NavigateToNext()
        {
            this.tasks.MoveNext();
            Rebind();
        }

        private MvxCommand previousCommand;
        public MvxCommand PreviousCommand
        {
            get
            {
                this.previousCommand = this.previousCommand ?? new MvxCommand(NavigateToPrevious, CanNavigatePrevious);
                return this.previousCommand;
            }
        }

        private bool CanNavigatePrevious()
        {
            return this.tasks.CanMovePrevious;
        }

        public void NavigateToPrevious()
        {
            this.tasks.MovePrevious();
            Rebind();
        }
    }
```

I tried all kind of things. At the moment i get an exception that the `MainView` cannot be found. Which i partly understand. in App.cs `MainViewModel` is the start up. But the controller is called `RootViewController`. I think the `RootviewController` should bind to my `MainViewModel`. But i don't know how.

How should I make MvvmCross with iOs working? 
How should I name the parts?

Answer (score 0):

MvvmCross' default view finder will look for a view called MainView.  That view should be derived from MvxViewController or another IMvxTouchView type.    If you don't want to name your view controller "MainView" then you need to create a custom view resolver.

My advice:  just rename your RootViewController to MainView.

Comment: I get a MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type MainView. Is it uncommon to use mvvmcross with storyboards? I can't find a sample with the latest release of mvvmcross which actually works.